# does elasticsearch-2 is compatible on upgrading kibana from version 4.5 to 5.x or 6.x

Tags: elasticsearch-2.0, kibana-5

We are planning to upgrade kibana from version 4.5 to version 5 or 6
Below is existing version stack, anyone help whether only kibana up-gradation is compatible or not.

Logstash
Version:-2.3.3

Elasticsearch
Version:-2.3.2

Kibana
Version:-4.5.0-linux-x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upgrade Kibana, you will definitely need to upgrade Elasticsearch. Logstash upgrade is not needed but recommended if you want to take advantage of some new features.

You can check out the Elastic Support Matrix here for version compatibility: https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_compatibility

Later versions of Elasticsearch and Kibana have to be the exact same version as plugins for both are version specific

Make sure that you are aware of any big changes between major version upgrades and look into the proper upgrade process for the specific version you are looking to change to: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/setup-upgrade.html